# Is there a way to limit the scope of \usepackage?

Tags: packages, grouping, package-options, breqn

When I tried to use the `breqn` package suggested by an answer to the question

[How do I break a long equation over lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578127/how-do-i-break-a-long-equation-over-lines)

It managed to break a whole bunch of unrelated equations (equations that did not use its functionality), including a definition for the control sequence `\mf` which I had previously defined myself.

Is there a way to limit the scope of a `\usepackage` declaration so that its (positive and negative) effects are limited to a particular segment of a document?

I have tried putting it inside an environment, but get the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.
```

Comment: You can only load a package in the preamble. The scope starts where you import the package and lasts until the end of the `document` environment.

Comment: It is probably easier to adjust your definition of `\mf` instead of trying to load `breqn` locally.

Comment: If you can provide the parts of the code that are failing (a full working example), we might be able to help in fixing the code so everything compiles correctly.

Comment: although the question as phrased has global interest, this case is likely to be specific to `breqn`, so i added that as a tag.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps for some small package this could be possible, but the general answer is no. In particular, `breqn` and its companion package `flexisym` do very extensive changes to the normal setup of math formulas which are, in some cases, global; therefore, even if it were possible to load them in a group, the changes would be performed also at the outer level. The same is true for many other packages.

It's not to be neglected that many commands that are used in packages are disabled after `\begin{document}` and this makes quite difficult to cope with the task of loading a package after the document has begun.

Answer (score 1):

If instead of using `\usepackage` you use `\input`, you can limited the scope of the package. It will require redefining some commands and patching others, but it should be technically possible. For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \begingroup
    \makeatletter
      \renewcommand{\usepackage}[1]{\input{#1}}
      \renewcommand{\NeedsTeXFormat}[1]{}
      \renewcommand{\ProvidesPackage}[1]{}
      \usepackage{fixltx2e.sty}
    \makeatother
  \endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps this can work for some packages, but there are *many* commands that are disabled after `\begin{document}` and that are used in packages, for instance `\RequirePackage`. Global definitions performed by a package may disrupt the working of the whole system.

Comment: @egreg You're very polite. I would have said that this solution looks a bit like calibrating your dosimeter with a hydrogen bomb...