# Assertions in Latex

Tags: macros, tex-core, best-practices

I am writing a long latex document and use many macros for defining mathematical symbols. I would like to ensure that there is no clash in the notation. For example, something like

```
\newcommand{\symbolone}{A}
\newcommand{\symboltwo}{A}
```

should not happen. Is there something like an assertion in latex such that I can do

```
\assert{\symbolone != \symboltwo}
```

?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Nice first question. You could make it even better by adding a small [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that we can start working with for testing solutions.

Comment: There is no “register” of all defined macros, so it's impossible to test each pair to see whether they do the same thing.

Comment: You can test if two macros have the same definition (with `\ifx`) but for example if `\symbolone` is `\hat{A}` and `\symboltwo is `\hat A` they are not equal with `\ifx`, but typeset to the same thing in all cases. So it is difficult to have a robust test that matches common expectations.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 6):

My solution introduces the macro `\singledef` which defines control sequence (like `\def`) but provides two more features:

- it checks if the control sequence is defined. If yes, then error message is printed and the control sequence keeps its original meaning.
- it saves the name of defined control sequence into the `\singledeflist` internal macro. When the next control sequence is defined via `\singledef` then it is defined but it is checked if the same control sequence (equivalent via `\ifx`) was defined and saved in `\singledeflist`. If yes, then error message is printed and the new control sequence is kept undefined.

The code:

```
\def\singledeflist{}

\def\singledef#1{% 
   \ifx#1\undefined
      \def\next{\singledefA#1}%
      \afterassignment\next
      \expandafter\def\expandafter#1%
   \else
      \errmessage{The \string#1 is defined already}% 
      \expandafter\def\expandafter\tmp
   \fi
}
\def\singledefA#1{\def\next{\singledefB#1}\expandafter\next\singledeflist\end}
\def\singledefB#1#2{%
   \ifx#2\end
      \expandafter\def\expandafter\singledeflist\expandafter{\singledeflist#1}% 
   \else
      \ifx#1#2%
         \errmessage{The \string#1 is the same as \string#2}%
         \let#1=\undefined
         \singledefC
      \fi
      \expandafter\next
   \fi
}  
\def\singledefC#1\end{\fi\fi}

\singledef\A{aha}  % this is like \def\A{aha}
\singledef\B{bha}  % this is like \def\B{bha}
\singledef\C{bha}  % this prints the error: The \C is the same as \B
```

Answer (score 2):

@egreg has shown how to compare two fully expanded strings ([On testing two fully expanded character strings for equality](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59565/on-testing-two-fully-expanded-character-strings-for-equality/59671#59671)), and you could apply his technique here.

I have added an error message in case you reuse a symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

\newcommand{\symbolI}{A}
\newcommand{\symbolII}{\pi r^2}
\newcommand{\symbolIII}{\pi r^2}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\TestSameSymbols}[2]{%
    \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{#1}{#2}=\z@ 
        \typeout{%
            ERROR: \noexpand#2 (#2) is the same as \noexpand#1.%
        }
    \fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\TestSameSymbols{\symbolI}{\symbolII}
\TestSameSymbols{\symbolII}{\symbolIII}

\[ \symbolI = \symbolII \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: as egreg warns in the referenced answer this isn't really safe for anything other than letters, try `\newcommand{\symbolIII}{\sqrt{x}}
`

Comment: What's `\expandafter` for?

Comment: Well, I wanted to typeout the expansion of #2 and didn't realize it happened automatically. Thanks--I fixed it.