# Is there a standard way to assert the engine used or similar and cause an error otherwise?

Tags: pdftex, luatex

Is there something analogous to the `assert` command offered by various programming languages to assert certain conditions?

In particular I am looking for a way to outfit my `.tex` files with assertions about the engine used (e.g. LuaLaTeX or PDFLaTeX). I know I can use `ifluatex` to check for it being used, but that still requires me to use a rather verbose notation of what I want (besides, I still haven't figured out how to throw an error and show a message of my choice).

So just to clarify: I am looking for a primitive like `assert` that will cause an error if the assertion isn't satisfied and will not do anything otherwise. The only other question regarding assertions which I could find was [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/228496/3925), but the answers dodge that and instead provide solutions tailored to the question. **I am looking for a generic way to assert certain conditions, though.**

Comment: The `ifxetex` package offers `\RequireXeTeX` which raises an error.  Unfortunately `ifluatex` doesn't seem to have a counterpart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way to detect LuaTeX is to check for the `\directlua` primitive before loading the documentclass or packages.  To raise an error use `\errmessage`.  After the error, I call `\@@end` to terminate the LaTeX run and prevent the user from continuing by just pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>.

```
\ifdefined\directlua\else
  \errmessage{LuaTeX is required to typeset this document}
  \csname @@end\expandafter\endcsname
\fi
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

```
$ pdflatex test.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
! LuaTeX is required to typeset this document.
l.2 ...uaTeX is required to typeset this document}

? 
 )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make a file called `assert.tex` like

```
\RequirePackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@assert
\newcommand\assert[1]{%
  \@asserttrue
  \csname assert@#1\endcsname
  \if@assert\else
    \@latex@error{Assert failed: #1}{This document requires #1}%
    \expandafter\@@end
  \fi
}
\@onlypreamble\assert

\newcommand{\def@assert}[2]{\@namedef{assert@#1}{#2}}

\def@assert{xetex}{\ifxetex\else\@assertfalse\fi}
\def@assert{luatex}{\ifluatex\else\@assertfalse\fi}
\def@assert{a4paper}{%
  \ifdim\paperheight=297mm
    \ifdim\paperwidth=210mm
    \else
      \@assertfalse
    \fi
  \else
    \@assertfalse
  \fi
}

\makeatother
```

and put it in a location searched by TeX engines. I added three assertions by way of example.

If your file has the form

```
\input{assert}

\documentclass{article}

\assert{luatex}
\assert{a4paper}

\begin{document}

Hello world!

\end{document}
```

then processing it with `pdflatex` or `xelatex` would stop with

```
! LaTeX Error: Assert failed: luatex.
```

Processing it with `lualatex` will stop with

```
! LaTeX Error: Assert failed: a4paper.
```

Adding `a4paper` to the document class options will make the document compilable with `lualatex`.

This doesn't check for the argument to be a valid assertion; an unknown one will be treated as if it is satisfied.

Comment: Thanks, and if I understand it correctly, this still will not allow you to check an arbitrary condition without adjusting `assert.tex`, right?

Comment: @0xC0000022L Yes, you have to code anything you need to assert. The package `iftex` codes some for engines, but otherwise this is virgin territory.