# unicode-math replaces \not by the number "6"

Tags: math-mode, xetex, symbols, unicode-math

The following MWE yields the attached picture:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
With \LaTeX{} commands:
\begin{gather*}
  A \not= B\\
  A \not\le B\\
  A \not\lesssim B\\
  A \not\approxeq B
\end{gather*}

With Unicode characters:

\begin{gather*}
  A \not= B\\
  A \not≤ B\\
  A \not≲ B\\
  A \not≊ B
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image: number 6]

Why is `\not` replaced by `6`?

I tried using a Unicode `combining long solidus overlay` instead, but that doesn't work at all:

```
\begin{gather*}
  A ≠ B\\
  A ≰ B\\
  A ≴ B\\
  A ≊̸ B
\end{gather*}
```

Comment: I guess, this is due to Unicode font fallback for unsupported characters.

Comment: `\not` is very broken in `unicode-math`.

Comment: @Gipfeli No; setting `\setmathfont{XITS Math}` or similar doesn't change anything.

Comment: @egreg Thanks :) Do you know how I can disable unicode math temporarily to input that character, then? There's no single unicode character for the combination `\not\approxeq`

Comment: You can make your own `\notapproxeq`: `\def\notapproxeq{\mathrel/\joinrel\mkern-8mu\approxeq}` and use it like  `$A \notapproxeq B$`

Comment: @alwaysask Thanks; the spacing is wrong though. Do you know if there's a way to temporarily disable `unicode-math`, for just one symbol?

Comment: I don't think you can disable packages, see [How to undo \usepackage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112713/how-to-undo-usepackage/112733#112733). The spacing can be tweaked: `\def\notapproxeq{\,\mathrel/\joinrel\mkern-8.5mu\approxeq}`.  It turns out the `\not` definition in unicode-math looks for an already defined \not version of the symbol so just by inserting the new definition in the preamble the `A \not\approxeq B` bit gets fixed.

Comment: If you already input Unicode, why not use the appropriate glyphs: `≠` (`\ne`), `≰` (`\nleq`), `≴` (`\nlesssim`)?  Unfortunately, `≊̸` is not mapped by `unicode-math`, so you have to build this one yourself: `\def\napproxeq{\mathpalette\donot\approxeq}
\def\donot#1#2{{\ooalign{$#1#2$\cr\hidewidth$#1\divslash$\hidewidth\cr}}}` or use `≇` (`\ncong`).

Comment: @HenriMenke because the only one I care about is \not\approxeq :) I already use unicode for the other ones.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this has been fixed in the most recent version of `unicode-math.sty`, January 8, 2018.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a suitable unicode char exists for a combination `\not` + unicode symbol you can add the needed declarations and they will work like the combination of `\not` + command. But imho there is no \not\approxeq, so here one needs a fallback like a combination with a solidus. You get a 6 in this case as there  seem to be a bug in unicode-math: it looses the definition of \not from unicode-math-tables. This seems to be a work around (but imho doesn't looks perfect).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_gset:cpn { not≤ }    { \nleq }
\cs_gset:cpn { not≲ }    { \not\lesssim }
%Fallback bug correction:
\__um_sym:nnn {"00338}{\__um_oldnot:                     }{\mathaccent}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
With \LaTeX{} commands:
\begin{gather*}
  A \not= B\\
  A \not\le B\\
  A \not\lesssim B\\
  A \not\approxeq B
\end{gather*}

With Unicode characters:

\begin{gather*}
  A \not= B\\
  A \not≤ B\\
  A \not≲ B\\
  A \not≊ B
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit

One get a better "fallback" \not if one uses the `overlay` keyword. **This works only with lualatex**: As an example here for for your \approxeq:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

%\setmathfont{Cambria Math}

\newcommand\napproxeq{\Umathaccent overlay fixed  7\symoperators "00338 \approxeq}

\begin{document}
$A \napproxeq B $

$A \not\approxeq C $

\end{document}
```

[image]

I will add this to the issue tracker for unicode math.

Comment: Right, but this doesn't look very good at all :/

Comment: I know, But you can change the definition of `\__um_oldnot:`  to improve the look. This won't affect the correct symbols.

Comment: Ah, neat :) In you examples, I feel that there is an issue with how it's positioned, too: it seems to be higher than in the other symbols.

Comment: @Clément: I added an edit for a better fallback not.

Comment: Thanks :) Now I really don't know which answer to accept ^^ Question: do you think the code that you wrote could be integrated as a general fix in unicode-math? It seems to have few dependencies, right?

Comment: I wouldn't use Stevens code if not needed. It doesn't scale correcty (try \not= in a subscript), and it affects also combinations for which negated glyphs exist (copy & paste e.g. ≠ to see the difference). Beside this I think that you identified two bugs and that unicode-math should fix them.

Answer (score 2):

Locally redefine `\not` as a stack.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\not[1]{%
  \mathrel{\ensurestackMath{\stackengine{0pt}{#1}{\mkern1mu/}{O}{c}{F}{T}{L}}}}%
}

\begin{document}
With \LaTeX{} commands:
\begin{gather*}
  A \not= B\\
  A \not\le B\\
  A \not\lesssim B\\
  A \not\approxeq B
\end{gather*}

With Unicode characters:

\begin{gather*}
  A \not= B\\
  A \not≤ B\\
  A \not≲ B\\
  A \not≊ B
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For comparison, here is the original unrepaired code.

[image]

Comment: Thanks; very nice! Do you think this could be a valuable patch to `unicode-math`?

Comment: @Clément I imagine a package like `unicode-math` would prefer to not rely on external packages like `stackengine`.  Also, as is, this answer does not translate to smaller math styles, though I can revise & extend to do so, if that is important.

Comment: I don't particularly need the smaller styles :) Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Better use `\divslash` than `/`.  The plain `/` is much too long in my opinion.

Comment: @HenriMenke `\divslash` looks good over something like `=`; however, it is far worse looking, in my opinion, when placed over things like `\le`, and`\lesssim`.  It's a toss-up for `\approxeq`.