# `\not` does not work with unicode-math

Tags: unicode-math

I’m using TeXLive 2015 and compile with lualatex or xelatex.

When loading the `unicode-math` package, the command `\not` produces a ‘6’ instead of striking through stuff (as in ‘ø’ with `\not o`).

The following example code

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

    \usepackage{
        fontspec,
        unicode-math,
    }

\begin{document}
    $\not o$.
\end{document}
```

produces the following output:

[image: 6 o]

I tried to googe this, but couldn’t find any results.
It seems unusual that noone else had this issue before – is this intended behaviour? If so, how do I get what I what, namely a ‘ø’ (and actually, I need the result of `\not \mapsto`)?

I have uploaded a paste of a compiilation’s log under http://pastebin.com/bdinUAT2.

Comment: https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/363#issuecomment-239785534 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324427/unicode-math-replaces-not-by-the-number-6

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yeah. I did not try hard enough googling that.

Comment: But you do not want simply `\varnothing`?

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke It’s actually about `\not \mapsto`.