# Issue with bm and breqn packages - is there a way to use a package in only part of a document?

Tags: packages, amsmath, bold, breqn

I am a long time stack exchange reader. I always found useful information here. This is however my first post.

I have a little issue that I am working on that maybe someone can provide a quicker fix.

I have a TeX document with hundreds of equations. Most of which use the `bm` package. 
I also have many equations that are several lines long. These were generated with Maple and have many `\left \right` commands in them. As a result, the package `\usepackage{breqn}` works very well in organizing them.

It is a known issue that the `bm` package and the `breqn` package cause each other much pain.

My issue is that I would like to use the `\usepackage{breqn}` in part of my document and then not use it in another part of the document. 
Is this possible?

Thank you!

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[12pt]{asme2ej}
\usepackage{amsmath}    % need for subequations
\usepackage{graphicx}   % need for figures
\usepackage{verbatim}   % useful for program listings
\usepackage{color}      % use if color is used in text 
\usepackage{subfigure}  % use for side-by-side figures
\usepackage{hyperref}   % use for hypertext links, including those to external documents and URLs
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{multirow} % for tables (multirow tables)
\usepackage{cite}    % to group lots of citations
\usepackage{paralist}  \setdefaultitem{}{\textbullet}{$\star$}{}% formats for some list styles
\usepackage{setspace}   % for double space command

\usepackage{breqn}     % break equation line automatically  ******* this packages does not like the \bm package *******
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{dmath}
 - \bm c \left( \cos \left( \theta \right) {\theta_{{d}}}^{2}+\theta_{{{\it 
dd}}}\sin \left( \theta \right)  \right) -l_{{{\it rdd}}}\sin \left( 
\mu \right) \cos \left( \gamma \right) -2\,l_{{{\it rd}}} \left( -\sin
 \left( \mu \right) \sin \left( \gamma \right) \gamma_{{d}}+\cos
 \left( \gamma \right) \cos \left( \mu \right) \mu_{{d}} \right) -l_{{
r}} \left( -\gamma_{{{\it dd}}}\sin \left( \gamma \right) \sin \left( 
\mu \right) -\gamma_{{d}} \left( \cos \left( \mu \right) \sin \left( 
\gamma \right) \mu_{{d}}+\sin \left( \mu \right) \cos \left( \gamma
 \right) \gamma_{{d}} \right) +\mu_{{{\it dd}}}\cos \left( \gamma
 \right) \cos \left( \mu \right) +\mu_{{d}} \left( -\sin \left( \gamma
 \right) \cos \left( \mu \right) \gamma_{{d}}-\cos \left( \gamma
 \right) \sin \left( \mu \right) \mu_{{d}} \right)  \right) =x_{{{\it 
dd}}}
\end{dmath}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! No, you can't disable `breqn`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100262/is-there-a-way-to-limit-the-scope-of-usepackage

Comment: Thanks egreg! It seems my alternative is to use \mathbf x instead of \bm x.

Comment: Can you add a small example of an equation that gives problems?

Comment: I just pasted an example equation that uses the referred to packages together. I have other equations that have many many /bm commands (I can't post for copywrite reasons).

Comment: I get no error. What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: The distribution I was using is a couple years old. This is because I am using Kile via Macports. If I switch to TeXshop (latest distribution) it works well! Interesting.

Comment: Avoid the MacPorts TeX Live. You can configure Kile to use the MacTeX distribution, just change the paths to use `/usr/texbin/pdflatex` and similar.

Comment: The example in the question runs without error in texlive 2013 and produces a bold *c* and breaks the equation over 5 lines.

Comment: Thank you David. Just a follow up. It seems that the main issue was caused mainly by the ASME class file \documentclass[12pt]{asme2ej}. It can be obtained here: http://goo.gl/iQPGcZ . Although, I'm sure the distribution helped with some of the package conflicts, they still remained when I compiled with asme2ej.cls. I switched to a different class file and everything is working well.

Comment: It is interesting, as that class file is widely used in the research community. I'm sure the community as a whole would be interested in a fix (assuming I am not the only one experiencing this). Although, as far as I am concerned, I will go forward with another class file.

Comment: In case there is interest, here is an external link to the class file http://iel.ucdavis.edu/code/ASME/journals-1.0/asme2ej.cls   Cheers,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With an up-to-date TeX distribution the file runs fine with the `article` class. With `asme2ej` it doesn't, but for a very simple reason: the class does

```
\RequirePackage{times}
\RequirePackage{mathptm}
```

The `times` and `mathptm` packages have been obsolete for at least eight years (probably more; the current version of `mathptmx` was released in 2005).

The correct call should be

```
\RequirePackage{mathptmx}
```

but this wouldn't solve the problem either. In order to have a chance to work, the `bm` package needs bold versions of the math fonts, which `mathptmx` doesn't provide. In this case `bm` resorts to doing “poor man's bold”, which breaks `breqn`.

You'll be luckier if you load

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

in your document. The math fonts are slightly different (but better) than those obtained with `mathptmx`.

---

A comment. While I can understand your need to rely on Maple output because of the great number of equation, I believe that writing mathematics is not simply jotting down long formulas in a way that the reader can't follow without rewriting them. The output I get from your example is simply unreadable.

[image]

There are too many useless parentheses: writing “sin(*x*)” instead of the customary “sin *x*” is distracting. The constants that multiply the sines and cosines are sometimes at the left and sometimes at the right without apparent reasons. Only two parentheses are made bigger (because of wrong usage of `\left` and `\right`); the unique exponent is placed wrongly.

Comment: egreg, thank you very much for your answer and time. I also agree with you about the portrayal of the mathematics. I have decided to manually go through each equation and make sure they are properly portrayed. I have many many relations much more complicated than the above, however for me it is worth the extra effort.

Comment: I do find it odd that a reputable algebraic manipulator engine would then convert TeX equations slightly wrongly. Interesting.

Comment: @FeX Unfortunately, it seems that who programmed the translation didn't know TeX very well.