# Boldmath (\bm) seems to break when used with \underset

Tags: underbrace, boldmath

Since upgrading to the latest version of TeXLive last month, I've noticed a few things breaking that used to work before.  For some reason, the use of \bm in the context of an \underset command gives a "fatal error" warning (and TexShop stops compiling).  I want to bold the variable "Y" in the equation below (and not the expression in the underset):

```
\begin{equation}
\underset{\strut n \times 1}{\bm{Y}} = b
\end{equation}
```

The above gives me an error (again, this used to work!!).

However, the following does work (and bolds everything -- the expression in the underset and the variable):

```
\begin{equation}
\bm{ \underset{\strut n \times 1}{Y} }  = b
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Experience the same issue with \boldsymbol and other bolding commands.  Anyone know a workaround to not bold the entire expression?

Comment: Either there is something you do not show or an issue with your installation, `\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\underset{\strut n \times 1}{\bm{Y}} = b
\end{equation}
\end{document}` runs through without error on my updated TeXLive2020 installation.

Comment: Thanks @Schrödinger'scat for your comment; your code worked. I think I may have found the culprit.  I tried selectively turning on/off other packages and it turns out the \usepackage{breqn} (which I use to break up long equations) seems to cause the error.  Could I request that you verify the same?

Comment: I confirm the `\usepackage{breqn}` causes issues. I also want to point out that `breqn` is *very* high on the "do not load this one" list, at least for me. There may also be a relation to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/146459/194703), but personally I'd just drop `breqn`.

Comment: Thank you again, @Schrödinger'scat, for confirming.  And also for warning me about \breqn.  I think the alternative is to use \multiline that is built into amsmath.  Is that you also recommend?  Or is there something else that you prefer for breaking up large equations?

Comment: Frankly, I am a fan of avoiding ultra-long equations that no one reads. One often can break up the equation in expressions and just have a short, crisp equation for those. But yes, if a long equation is truly unavoidable, one can use `multline`, or `align` with `\MoveEqLeft` from `mathtools`.

Comment: please always post complete documents not just fragments neither the title nor the text of the question mentions the actual issue here, which makes it hard to answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - your point is noted.  In fact, the issue was related to another installed package ... I did not post it but realized later (based on Schrodinger's cat comments) that that might be what is breaking this.