# Issue with psgo.sty when using it in Spanish

Tags: packages

I've been working with psgo.sty (it allows to draw nice Go diagrams). Go diagrams are "enumerated" on the vertical axis with letters from A to T (Go is played on a 19x19 board, and I is omitted probably to avoid confusions with L. Letters go from A to T and not from A to S because in Go, lines, ant not squares, are used to place the stones):

A B C D E F G H J K L M N O P Q R S T

The issue has arose when I'm creating a document in Spanish, and now the vertical axes goes from A to S, because Ñ is added to the list:

A B C D E F G H J K L M N Ñ O P Q R S

Which is not desirable; I want a proper "international" Go diagram, with horizontal axis going from A to T and without "Ñ".

The minimal code that reproduces this issue is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{psgo}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{psgoboard}
\end{psgoboard}

\end{document}
```

This gives place to a nice Go diagram, but with the "Ñ" letter in the horizaontal coordinates (simply removing the "\usepackage[spanish]{babel}" line "solves" the issue):
[image: Go diadram created with psgo with undesirable "Ñ" on the vertical axis]

So as you can imagine this is not the proper way to print a Go diagram, no matter the text is in Spanish.

I've tried to contact the developer, Victor Bos, but the email in the documentation doesn't work any more.

In any case, I just don't have any idea either the fixing is trivial or way too complex, so I wonder if some expert could take a look at the code, or give me a couple of hints on how to try to solve it by myself (I have some background on programming on C and python).

Best

Emilio

Comment: Make a complete minimal example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: please don't use addresses in the form you gave: the package is at `http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/psgo/` (using the mirror selector link); of course, any reader can get to the package via the ctan package list `http://www.ctan.org/pkg/`, anyway

Comment: I was thinking of "unusing" the Spanish package whenever I'm drawing a diagram, but I've seen it's not possible:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100262/is-there-a-way-to-limit-the-scope-of-usepackage?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

The trick is pretending that Ñ occupies the same vertical space as A

```
% arara: latex
% arara: dvips
% arara: ps2pdf

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{psgo}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\renewcommand{\golabelformat}[1]{{\sffamily\vphantom{A}\smash{#1}}}


\begin{document}

\begin{psgoboard}
\end{psgoboard}

\end{document}
```

The `arara` lines are for avoiding me to run three programs instead of one.

[image]

If you want English style alphabet, then you can load `babel` with the `es-nolayout` option:

```
% arara: latex
% arara: dvips
% arara: ps2pdf

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{psgo}
\usepackage[spanish,es-nolayout]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{psgoboard}
\end{psgoboard}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need in the text alphabetically enumerated lists that have more than thirteen items, then you have to follow a different pattern:

```
% arara: latex
% arara: dvips
% arara: ps2pdf

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\makeatletter
\let\latex@Alph\@Alph % save the original meaning of \@Alph
\makeatother

\usepackage{psgo}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\golabelformat}[1]{%
  {% open a group
   \let\@Alph\latex@Alph % restore temporarily the original meaning
   \sffamily\vphantom{A}\smash{#1}%
  }% close the group
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{psgoboard}
\end{psgoboard}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same as with `es-nolayout`; the difference is that the fourteenth item in an alphabetically enumerated list will have the “Ñ” label.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't explain myself properly when posting my question. The issue is not the "Ñ" bein placed a bit lower than it should, but that it appears at all.
PS: I don't know what's more disappointing, not being able to explain myself in English or not being able to tell whether someone is pulling my leg.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, not exactly fixing the .sty file, but here someone posted a way to solve the issue:
http://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/2j1q3c/hints_for_modifying_a_sty_file/